# AngularJS marker coordinates are not being updated in model

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I' was trying out angular map and I faced a problem which was related to getting map marker position and display it when marker is moved. But marker model was not updated when marker was moved. I used the official example and solve the problem by changing the dragend event. I used the apply to change the marker coordinates value

```
events: {
    dragend: function (marker, eventName, args) {
        $log.log('marker dragend');
        $log.log(marker.getPosition().lat());
        $log.log(marker.getPosition().lng());
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.marker.coords.latitude = marker.getPosition().lat();
            $scope.marker.coords.longitude = marker.getPosition().lng();
        });
    }
}
```

The complete example can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GSHDy0NEnk36G7gWNoj0?p=preview).

But I'm not satisfied with this approach. Is there any solution where I do not need to put in this block to update marker coords

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.marker.coords.latitude = marker.getPosition().lat();
    $scope.marker.coords.longitude = marker.getPosition().lng();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to send updated data to your directive.

1. $apply: If you want to update data which is coming from parent controller and other directives are also using the same then use this. However, after this function $digest will call to update local variables.
2. $digest: If you want to update directive level scope variables then you can directly call this method.